# Regular expression to select case name

Tags: regex

I need regular expression to select only one

> Case

name from text with

> Id=2

.
I've tried this one: `(?<=Case:)[\s\S]*?(?:(?!Id=2).)*`
This expression selects all of them. What expression should be correct?
Text is:

> Case:A    Test    Id=1    Time End Case:B     Test    Id=2    Time End Case:C     Test
>     Id=3    Time End

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
\bCase:(?:[^IC]|\B[IC]|I(?!d=)|C(?!ase:))*Id=2(?!\d)
```

The idea is to avoid to match one more time the words "Id" or "Case" between "Case:" and the "Id" you are looking for, using negated character classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to match `B`, which contains the string `Id=2`. If yes, then try the below regex,

```
Case\s*:\s*\K[A-Z](?=\s*\S*\s*Id=2)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aB8vN8/3)